# Google Place Auto Complete

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to add the google place auto complete feature it worked perfect but everytime i click on it to search for my location the my the keyboard shows and then disppears immidiately

code xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

java code

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            location = place.getName().toString();

            FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String user_id = current_user.getUid();
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("User location", location);


            mDatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Intent addlocation = new Intent(selectlocation.this, home.class);
                        addlocation.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(addlocation);
                        finish();


                    }

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    });
```

and also i havent tested it, but help me check the java code if the used it correctly.. i am trying to send the user location to my firbase database,i dont if that code is correct cause i havent tested it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Make sure you enable Google Places API for Android and not just Places API in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com). "Places API for Android" will not show up under APIs & Auth/APIs because it isn’t a popular API (yet). You will have to search for it using the API search box.