# onActivityResult not called for intent

Tags: android

I tried making a places autocomplete using google Places API based on googles sample but I am facing a problem that is it does not call the onActivityResult method. I have read the previous thread but it is not very helpful. This is my code :

```
public class AutoCompleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_autocomplete);

}

public void findPlace(View view) {
    try {
        Intent intent =
                new PlaceAutocomplete
                        .IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("======");
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // retrive the data by using getPlace() method.
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber());

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.searched_address))
                    .setText(place.getName()+",\n"+
                            place.getAddress() +"\n" + place.getPhoneNumber());

        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.e("Tag", status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
            finish();
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is my xml file if its needed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    tools:context=".AutoCompleteActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findPlace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search Google Places"
        android:onClick="findPlace"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/findPlace"
        android:id="@+id/searched_address"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I cant seem to get suggestions for google API - (Not GOOGLE API KEY NOT ENABLED PROBLEM), it keeps loading and finally failed.

Comment: where you calling method **findPlace** ?

Comment: I called it in my xml file onclick activity for the button

Answer (score 0):

have you put this tag in manifest file...
        meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXBsWU9seEWmlB-CMc_pxZ358b4-esTNR5I" />**

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154839/google-place-auto-complete/52159660#52159660